# Let $p(x)=(\frac12)^x, x=1,2,3,\ldots$ , zero elsewhere, be the p.m.f. of the random variable $X$. Find the m.g.f., the mean, and the variance of $X$.

Tags: probability-theory

I was able to attain the m.g.f. and the mean, but my variance isn't matching the textbook solution, so just wanted to see if I'm not doing something correctly.

---

We are given that
$$
p(x)=
\begin{cases}
\left(\frac12\right)^x,&x=1,2,3,\ldots\\
0,&\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$
The moment generating function, or m.g.f., is defined as $M(t)=E(e^{tX})$. Thus we have
\begin{align}
M(t)&=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}e^{tx}\left(\frac12\right)^x\\
&=\left(\frac12\right)^1e^{1t}+\left(\frac12\right)^2e^{2t}+\left(\frac12\right)^3e^{3t}+\cdots
\end{align}
We observe that this sum is an infinite geometric series with a constant ratio of $\frac12e^t$. Thus for $t<\ln2$, we have
\begin{align}
M(t)&=\frac{\frac12e^t}{1-\frac12e^t}\\
&=\frac{e^t}{2-e^t}
\end{align}
The mean of $X$ is the first moment of $X$, i.e. $E(X)$. We have the relationship that $\frac{d}{dt}M(t)|_{t=0}=E(X)$. And so
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}M(t)&=\frac{(2-e^t)e^t-(-e^t)e^t}{(2-e^t)^2}\\
&=\frac{2}{e^t}-\frac12+\frac{e^t}{2}
\end{align}
Plugging in $t=0$ we get $E(X)=2$.

In terms of the m.g.f., the variance of $X$ is defined as $Var(X)=M''(0)-[M'(0)]^2$. We have
\begin{align}
M''(t)&=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{2}{e^t}-\frac12+\frac{e^t}{2}\right)\\
&=-\frac{2}{e^t}+\frac{e^t}{2}
\end{align}
Therefore, $M''(0)=-2+\frac12=-\frac32$. And so $Var(X)=-\frac32-4=-\frac{11}{2}.$ My textbook is getting $Var(X)=2$ somehow. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: There is an error $\frac{(2-e^t)e^t-(-e^t)e^t}{(2-e^t)^2} \neq \frac{2}{e^t} - \frac{1}{2} +\frac{e^t}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplification
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}M(t)&=\frac{(2-e^t)e^t-(-e^t)e^t}{(2-e^t)^2}\\
&=\frac{2}{e^t}-\frac12+\frac{e^t}{2}
\end{align}
is not valid, and I'm not sure entirely what you're doing here; how can the denominator change from a power of $2-e^t$ to $e^t$?

Rather, we can simplify the numerator to $2e^t$, and get $\frac{2e^t}{(2-e^t)^2}$.

We still get $M'(0) = 2$, but now you should get a different second derivative, and ultimately get $M''(t) = 6$.

Comment: I completely made the worst algebra mistake...the denominator $(2-e^t)^2$ is equivalent to $4-4e^t+e^{2t}$ and I ended up dividing the numerator by the individual terms of this denominator...which is no good (I should probably take a break).